# ansible unable to find or access script

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook containing the following code:

```
---
- name: This is an example of successfully running a command on a server
hosts: user@myServer
  tasks:
  - name: create the file ansibleMadeThis
    command: touch ansibleMadeThis
```

I have set up ssh keys and when I run this playbook a file is made on myServer

However I would like to run a script on the server, so I read about the script module [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/script_module.html) and wrote this playbook:

```
---
- name: This is an attempt to run a script called script.sh on a remote server
  hosts: user@myServer
  tasks:
  - name: Run script
    script: /home/user/script.sh
```

On the server I have a script in ~ (aka /home/user) called script.sh. script.sh contains the following:

```
touch ansibleCalledTheScriptThatMadeThis
```

When logged into the server myself as user, running this script works fine, however when I run the playbook with the following command I get the following error:

```
ansible-playbook runScript.yml
```

error message:

```
fatal: [user@myServer]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Could not find or access '/home/user/script.sh' on the Ansible Controller.\nIf you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option"}
```

Also I have tried running the following:

```
---
- name: This is an attempt to run a script called script.sh on a remote server
  hosts: user@myServer
  tasks:
  - name: Run script
    command: /home/maxdeploy/script.sh
```

However it gives me this error:

```
fatal: [user@server]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/home/user/script.sh", "msg": "[Errno 8] Exec format error", "rc": 8}
```

Please note that I have the permissions on the file script.sh set to 777 (I did chmod 777 script.sh) so there shouldn't be any permissions problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that your script does not start with a "[shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))" marker:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

The "Exec format error" message that you're getting means that the kernel doesn't know how to execute the thing that you're trying to run.  I can replicate that exact behavior like this:

- First, we create a file with the content `echo hello world`

  ```
  $ echo "echo hello world" > script.sh
  ```
- Now we try to `exec` it:

  ```
  $ python -c 'import os; os.execve("./script.sh", ["script.sh"], {})'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
  ```

So add the `#!/bin/sh` marker to the top of your script, so that it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
touch ansibleCalledTheScriptThatMadeThis
```

...and it should run without a problem.